Debugging Pandas to_sql function
I use the following code to insert a DataFrame into an MS SQL Server database.
data is a pd.DataFrame that has the same columns as the database.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={connection_string}', fast_executemany=True)
with engine.connect() as connection:
    data.to_sql(
        'dbo.tablename',
        connection,
        if_exists='append',
        index=False,
        dtype={...}  # Correct mapping of columns in data to SQL data types.
        )

The code passes and I dont receive any error. However, the database does not change even though it should.
How can I debug this code?

Try using with engine.begin() instead of with engine.connect()

Since you are asking for "how can I debug this" I can suggest as two "sanity checks" first to make sure you are looking at the right database and the right server when you check your results (it is an easy mistake to make) and secondly you might like to try a read_sql just as another way to verify if this is working at all in terms of the connection and transfer of data.

.to_sql('dbo.tablename', won't work, you need to use to_sql('tablename', …, schema='dbo')

I finally managed to find the issue. There seems to be some strange behaviour going on in this part of the code:
data.to_sql('dbo.tablename', ...)

Using the prefix dbo. is very common in SSMS but pandas function to_sql() needs to take the table_name as the first argument, and specify the schema as "dbo" separately (docs). After removing dbo., the data is written to the database.
Edit:
So here is my final solution:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={connection_string}', fast_executemany=True)
with engine.connect() as connection:
    data.to_sql(
        'tablename',
        connection,
        if_exists='append',
        index=False,
        schema='dbo',
        dtype={...}  # Correct mapping of columns in data to SQL data types.
        )


According to the pandas documentation, this first argument should be the table name as a string, so including "dbo." is incorrect. You can read more to understand from pandas documentation directly - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

"sqlalchemy does not seem to support it" - Your beef is not with SQLAlchemy, it's with pandas. As I mentioned in my comment to the question, you need to specify the schema separately as .to_sql('tablename', …, schema='dbo')

True, I updated my answer. And thank you!
